# Python TypeHint a function that returns different types based on input

Tags: python, type-hinting, pylance

I have a method which works like this, with it normally being used to return a `Path`.

```py
from typing import Literal, Union
from pathlib import Path

def get_filename(return_type: Literal["Path", "str"]) -> Union[Path, str]:
    filename = "./foo/bar.csv"

    if return_type == "str":
        return filename
    elif return_type == "Path":
        return Path(filename)
    else:
        raise ValueError(
            f'Return type must be either "Path" or "str", not {return_type}'
        )


file = get_filename(return_type="Path")
print(file.is_file())
```

On the final line I get the following message from Pylance:

> (method) is_file: () -> bool | Unknown
> Whether this path is a regular file (also True for symlinks pointing to regular files).
> Cannot access member "is_file" for type "str"
> Member "is_file" is unknownPylancereportGeneralTypeIssues

Is there a way to correctly type hint this situation so that Pylance knows `file` is a `Path`? Or should I just make it always return Path and have another method which calls `get_filename` converts the output to string and then return that?

Thanks

**Edit 1**

I have just realised another, more common scenario:

```py
import pandas as pd

# returns dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(file)

# returns a series, Pylance doesn't know this
series = pd.read_csv(file, squeeze=True)
```

Here in pandas an input argument can change the output type and Pylance can also not deal with this. For Pylance to know `series` is a `pd.Series` you must do:

```py
# return series which pylance is happy with
df = pd.read_csv(file)
series = df.squeeze()
```

Comment: I recommend your latter solution: the function in question should return a `Path` object. Then the caller should decide if they want to convert to `str` or not. This solution is simple, works with type hinting, and [splits responsibilities](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: Thank you, I think I'll go with this as it'll be easier for other to follow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do this using [`typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload):

```py
from typing import Literal, overload
from pathlib import Path

@overload
def get_filename(return_type: Literal["Path"]) -> Path:...

@overload
def get_filename(return_type: Literal["str"]) -> str:...

def get_filename(return_type):
    # your code goes here
```

Comment: I wondered if there was something like `functools.singledispatchmethod` which didn't require duplicate code. I've tested your solution and it works, thank you.